# Segmentation fault and core dumped when trying to declare a big array

Tags: c, arrays

In my *C* program, when I try to assign this array value:

```
double sample[200000][2];
```

I get a segmentation fault error. But when I use:

```
double sample[20000][2]
```

it works!! Is there a limit to these index values?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you tried to reserve space for `200,000 x 2 = 400,000` double values, and each `double` is 8 bytes, so you tried to reserve around **3.2 Megabytes**.

Even though your machine likely has a couple Gigs of memory, stack space is limited per-process and per-thread and may well be limited to 1 or 2 megabytes.  So you cannot allocate 3 megs, and you crash.

To fix this, you want to change to dynamic memory, using [`malloc`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?malloc%203).
That will let you allocate from heap-space which is much more plentiful than stack-space.

To use malloc:

```
double (*sample) [200000];
s = malloc(sizeof(*sample) * 2); 
sample[0][0] = 0.0;
sample[1][199999] = 9.9;
```

Comment: @ZanLynx: You are partially right, I forgot a level of indirection (`*`).  Fixed now.

Comment: I have to agree with @ZanLynx I don't see how your allocation code works.

Comment: I edited your code example with one that I tried out.

Comment: @ZanLynx that is still wrong, so the `200000` *double* * will be in automatic storage and the much smaller second dimension will be dynamic which is definitely not the original intention.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Automatic storage? No. In the code above `sample` is a pointer to an array of 200,000 doubles. The `malloc(sizeof(*sample)*2)` requests dynamic allocation of two of those arrays for 400,000 doubles total.

Answer (score 6):

You are likely overflowing your stack, since that is a automatic variable in most modern implementation they will allocated on the stack which has limited size.

For example the stack size in [visual studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) defaults to `1MB` but is modifiable. There is a more complete list of typical stack sizes [here](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/doc/stackOverflow.txt):

```
SunOS/Solaris   8172K bytes
Linux           8172K bytes
Windows         1024K bytes
cygwin          2048K bytes
```

An alternative to allocating on the stack if you have a large amount of data is to use *dynamic allocation* via [malloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc). The *C FAQ* has a good reference on [How can I dynamically allocate a multidimensional array?](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html), modifying their two-dimensional example for *double*:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

double **array1 = malloc(nrows * sizeof(double *));
for(i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
   array1[i] = malloc(ncolumns * sizeof(double));
```

Comment: Just some more stack comments: Some systems have "unlimited" stack size, as it grows on demand. But when threading is added stacks suddenly have fixed size because each stack needs a unique location and will quickly run into neighboring memory allocations.

Comment: how can i modify the stack size ? i using gcc compiler here.

Comment: @james what operating system?

Comment: Linux stack information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656722/is-there-a-limit-of-stack-size-of-a-process-in-linux

Comment: @ZanLynx : do you perhaps happen to know what the standard says about the maximum array size? I guess it's implementation-defined, but I'm curious.

Comment: @James:  *"How can I modify the stack size?"* is the wrong question.  The proper question is *"How can I avoid allocating on the stack?"*

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar: I do not think the standard defines a minimum size. One a 16-bit computer, you'd be limited to 64KB objects for example. And yet, that used to be a common C programming environment.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar the standard does not talk about the stack it just talks about automatic storage duration.