# Stack Guard and Stack Smashing Protection - canaries, memory

Tags: linux, gcc, x86, stack-memory, hardening

I have a few questions about Stack Guard and SSP protections. First question is about Stack Guard and its three types of canaries, if I am correctly - terminator, random and random XOR.

1. I'd like to know, how to disabled Stack Guard on x86 Linux system? Somewhere I read, it's possible with this command, while compiling with gcc `-disable-stackguard-randomization`, it's same like with this command for enable `-enable-stackguard-randomization`, both doesn't work. If needed, my gcc version is 4.8.2.
2. Next question about Stack guard, when I will able to enable/disable it, how can I set, which type of canaries I want to use? What I read, terminator canaries are used by default, for random I have to compiled with `-enable-stackguard-randomization`, but how about random XOR? (Or with null 0x00000000)
3. Now about SSP(ProPolice), I know, for random canary I have to compiled with `fstack-protector-all`, but how about terminator, is it same as in Stack Guard, by default?
4. Last one, where I can find random canary in memory? For example, I have this scenario - compiled C program, like `gcc -g example.c -o example -fstack-protector-all`, so with random canaries. Let's say, I'm able to get address of canary, after every execution. So I expect `Canary = 0x1ae3f900`.

   From a different papers, I get some info, that canary is located in .bss segment. So I get address of .bss segment using readelf: `readelf -a ./example | grep bss`. It's 080456c9. In gdb I set some breakpoints, to get address of canary, but when I check .bss address `x/20x 0x080456c9`, all I see are only 0x00000000 addresses, but
   canary is nowhere. Plus, I checked `__stack_chk_fail`'s if it isn't there, but with same result, I can't see it there. I get address of stack_chk_fail from PLT/GOT.

Comment: Also see [Qualys Security Advisory - The Stack Clash](http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2017/06/19/1) on OSS-Security mailing list. Its shows off some neat tricks, and its pretty damning of the guard page. Its amazing how many OS'es they took down with it.

Comment: You can override the default by compilign with `gcc -fno-stack-protector` or `gcc -fstack-protector=strong`.  [When and how to use GCC's stack protection feature?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1629685) and https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#index-fstack-protector.  See also [Why does this memory address %fs:0x28 ( fs\[0x28\] ) have a random value?](//stackoverflow.com/q/10325713) which points out that normal stack-protector randomizes the stack cookie.

Comment: Correction, the option to enable it is `-fstack-protector-strong`, not `=`.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Smashing Protection (SSP) is an improvement over StackGuard. SSP was first  implemented in gcc 4.1.

> I'd like to know, how to disabled Stack Guard on x86 Linux system?

Use `-fno-stack-protector` to disable the userland SSP.

The `--disable-stackguard-randomization` and `--enable-stackguard-randomization` are build options for glibc source code.

> when I will able to enable/disable it, how can I set, which type of
>   canaries I want to use?

This is not configurable in gcc as far as I know. Since glibc 2.10, the stack canary is generated in a function called `_dl_setup_stack_chk_guard`. Here is some part of [its code](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/sysdeps/generic/dl-osinfo.h#L24):

```
  if (dl_random == NULL)
    {
      ret.bytes[sizeof (ret) - 1] = 255;
      ret.bytes[sizeof (ret) - 2] = '\n';
    }
  else
    {
      memcpy (ret.bytes, dl_random, sizeof (ret));
      ret.num &= ~(uintptr_t) 0xff;
    }
```

`dl_random` holds the address of the auxiliary vector entry for `AT_RANDOM`, which is a 16-byte random value initialized by the kernel while creating the process. If you are running on a kernel or an emulator that doesn't initialize `AT_RANDOM`, the check `dl_random == NULL` would be true and the canary used is the terminator value with the first and second most significant bytes initialized to 255 and `\n`, respectively. All other bytes are zero. Usually `AT_RANDOM` is initialized by the kernel and so the least 7 significant bytes of `AT_RANDOM` are copied. The last byte of canary is set to zero.

So if you want to use a particular method to generate the canary, you can change this code and build you own glibc.

As an alternative method, @PeterCordes have suggested in the comments to write your canary value to memory location `%%fs:0x28` (see the code below) at the top of the `main` function and restore the runtime-generated canary just before returning from `main`.

> Now about SSP(ProPolice), I know, for random canary I have to compiled
>   with 'fstack-protector-all', but how about terminator, is it same as
>   in Stack Guard, by default?

All variants of the `-fstack-protector` option use SSP. These don't affect how the canary is generated.

> Last one, if anyone of you, can tell me, where I can find random
>   canary in memory.

The canary is generated dynamically early at process startup; you can't use `readelf` to get the canary. According to [this](https://www.elttam.com.au/blog/playing-with-canaries/) article, you can use the following code to get the canary when compiling for i386:

```
int read_canary()
{
  int val = 0;
  __asm__("movl %%gs:0x14, %0;"
          : "=r"(val)
          :
          :);
  return val;
}
```

and for x86_64:

```
long read_canary()
{
  long val = 0;
  __asm__("movq %%fs:0x28, %0;"
          : "=r"(val)
          :
          :);
  return val;
}
```

Comment: *you can change this code and build you own glibc.*  Or potentially just write to `%%fs:0x28` at the top of main, and restore the original canary value before returning in case `main` itself or any CRT start functions used stack-protection.  Or call `exit` instead of letting `main` return so you don't need to restore the old stack canary.  IDK if an exception could unwind through main and lead to a stack-protector check fail, but probably not because any top-level exception catching probably aborts instead of returning.

Comment: If you call `exit` instead of returning from `main`, you don't need to restore the old stack canary.  `main`'s stack-cookie check code won't be reached (and its return address won't be used either).  So calling `exit` simplifies `main`.